# Zedgraph X Axis Pan or Zoom on C#

Tags: c#, plot, real-time, zedgraph

I try to search solution about pan to want area but i got nothing.

I am doing about real-time graph to collect data from Arduino sensors.

So far i can create a graph with data and created Textbox for input time(min).
I want zedgraph pan from Max x scale (current time) - input value(min). It like drag mouse to zoom but i want to specific time by input value.

Example:

I input value 30 in Textbox. Zedgraph will pan from Current time to 30 min before if i input 0 Zedgraph will zoom out all.

I try to get value from Textbox for set x axis min it can but when i zoom out the graph data before is disappear.

Anyone have any idea to do like that.

Thank you

Sorry for my weak English.

Comment: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266275/zedgraph-zooming-and-resizing)? 1st [google hit](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Zedgraph+pan+zoom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) of many..

Comment: No, I do not want to click zoom. i want to input value to zoom.